# Android Native C Code not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, android-ndk, native

Hey guys i have a real weird issue this time.

I reinstalled my ADT on a new computer. All native C includes are recognized by Eclipse and my code compiles perfectly with no errors nor warnings.

When i make the slightest change to my code, all lines including methods from native libraries become "Unresolved".

- Restarting Eclipse solves this, until the next edit.
- Editing java files is ok, only when i edit the C code it becomes unrecognizable to Eclipse.

Please help, restarting eclipse before every compilation is really not fun...
Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: It is not exactly a solution, but yes, switch to `Android Studio` (if you have time to do the switch)

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: I have tried cleaning my project. I have also manually removed C nature and added Native support back to the project. It did not solve my problem.

@Paschalis - Thank you for your suggestion, will look into it. Could you elaborate on why Eclipse would have this issue while Android Studio wont?